# Display issues Hybrid graphics ubuntu 16.04 +NVIDIA 8400M

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am a Linux and Ubuntu newbie, and converted an old laptop to run Ubuntu (sole OS). The Machine is Sony Vaio SZ VGN-SZ75GN/B, with Intel Core 2 Duo, 3GB RAM,  and NVIDIA GEFORCE 8400M GS GPU in a hybrid graphic configuration. Ubuntu is 16.04 LTS 32bit, and chksum verified before installation.

The problems are:

1. Sometimes at start-up, the screen just shows a black and white pattern and nothing happens
2. Sometimes it does start up, but as soon as I click the Ubuntu Icon, the screen goes garbled for a while, and resets when i click some other area
3. I tried the following commands and their results are:

   ```
   sudo grep -i switcheroo /boot/config-*
   /boot/config-4.4.0-31-generic:CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y
   /boot/config-4.4.0-59-generic:CONFIG_VGA_SWITCHEROO=y

   lspci -v |grep VGA
   01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G86M [GeForce 8400M GS] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
   ```

Please advise what can I do further to fix these issues. I don't intend to run games or like, so would be ok to use one or the other card.

Much appreciated...

Comment: Any reason for the 32bit? (Core2Duo is 64bit)

Comment: I had a vista 32-bit installation on it as OEM install - used that info and didn't research more before installing.